# Is the map data type in kotlin the same data type as the dictionary in python?

Tags: python, kotlin, dictionary

I have studied python for some time, I already understand data types in python programming, but now I'm studying kotlin language and I found the map data type in kotlin, and I think this data type is almost the same as a dictionary data type in python, is that so?

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that `Map` is an _interface_ in Kotlin. There are many different implementations (HashMap, TreeMap, LinkedHashMap…) using different data structures and algorithms, and having different memory usage, speed, and thread safety — but they all associate keys with values, and they all implement the same methods, so you can use them interchangeably. This is part of the [collections framework](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html), along with lists and sets.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, finally i understand about this

Comment: One big difference is that Kotlin is a statically typed language, which means when you create a `Map`, you have to specify the types of the data it holds - e.g. the keys are `String`s, and the values are `MyCoolClass`. In Python, because it's dynamically typed, you can throw anything in a `dict`, any types mixed and matched, and you just have to make sure when you pull a value out, you know what type it is. In Kotlin, if you want that kind of mixed data structure, you need to formally define an object with field `A` that holds a value of type `X`, field `B` holds type `Y` etc